# Different parameters in Meteor call stubs

Tags: meteor

I have a meteor method that's supposed to handle file/image uploads by passing a cdn key, which is just a string.

For latency compensation though, I want to add the actual image blob to LocalMongo, that way I can add an image preview.

This is a problem since I want to just pass a string key to my server method, while I want to pass a file blob to my client method stub. Does Meteor support this? I don't want to pass the image blob to my server (as doing so would serialize the blob/make the call costly).

A solution I'm thinking of is to just define two Meteor methods with different names, the first one being for the client and the other for the server, and just calling them both with the proper parameters. Is this the proper way to do this in Meteor?

*EDIT:* My solution above doesn't actually work because Meteor realizes there is no method on the server (and nukes the local changes of my client method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a suggestion, you can save the file blob in a Session variable and access in the method when the method stub is called from client, like this,

```
Meteor.methods({
    'yourMethod': function (key) {
        if (Meteor.isClient) {
            var fileBlob = Session.get('my-file-blob'); //set this variable just before calling this method. And don't forget to remove it when template is destroyed.

        } else {

        }
    }
});
```

Like I said, I didn't test it but just a suggestion. Hope it helps.

Comment: After scouring the docs as much as I can, it seems that keeping the data on local state like this seems like the only way to go.